# R Package tm.plugin.webmining does not work with R 3.1.0 (but does with R 2.1.5)

Tags: r, tm

I am using R 3.1.0, along with the tm.plugin.webmining package (within RStudio). Packages are installed fine (along with all dependencies) and I can load the library.

When I try to run a basic test however:

```
yahoocorpus<-WebCorpus(YahooNewsSource("Microsoft"))
```

I get:

```
Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object '.Source' not found
```

This does not occur if I point RStudio to R 2.1.5

I have looked online but not found any resolution of the issue (though somebody did suggest a hack of the source code). It would be great to understand exactly what is causing the problem (and what has changed between versions to make this happen (I also tried 3.0.1, and that also does not work)

Thanks again,

Alan

Answer (score 0):

I think that function WebCorpus does not exist in last version of TM package. Check the doc [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf)!

You have 3 possibilities : DirSource, VectorSource, or DataframeSource.

You can check the source on R with:

`{r}
library(tm)
getSources()`

Which should give you :

`[1] "DataframeSource" "DirSource"       "URISource"       "VectorSource"    "XMLSource"`

Cyrille